# How to solve $c_1x+c_2x^2+...+c_nx^n = K $ type equation (internal rate of return)

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, roots, finance

I'm trying to calculate internal rate of return and wonder how you would solve this equation

$50x + 20 x^2+75x^3 = 135.6$

The answer is $x = 0.9694$

But does anyone know how to do this step-by-step? Also is there any simple method for calculating $x$ when the equation does not have high exponentials? I.e.

Are the methods for solving

$c_1x+c_2x^2+...+c_nx^n = K $

The same as

$c_1x+c_2x^2+c_3x^3 = K$

Where c and K are constants.

Comment: you will need the formulas of Cardano

Comment: With these numbers, Cardano will give some monsters !

Comment: How about this "simple" equation: $x^5-x=1$? Turns out that there's no way to write $x$ exactly, using the standard functions. (If you replace the $5$ with a $4$ or $3$, you _can_ solve it exactly, but the expressions are hideously complicated.)

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger, what you say follows from Abel's theorem, I guess, right?

Comment: @SamratMukhopadhyay Not exactly. That theorem says there's no formula that works for all quintics, but it doesn't prove that there are specific quintics that can't be solved. Maybe they could all be solved, but you need a different formula for each one? As it turns out, some irreducible quintics _can_ be solved, and some can't. To show that $x^5-x-1$ is insolvable, you need Galois theory. (I'm not even sure how to prove it for that one, but Wolfram Alpha couldn't solve it, so I'm assuming it's insoluble.)

Comment: @SamratMukhopadhyay It turns out that $x^5+15x+12$ has a solution in terms of radicals, according to this paper I'm looking at.

Comment: Ah, correct, there can be different ways for different problems, but no general rule exists when degree $\ge 5$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, the question in interesting with respect to many items :

- for this kind of problems related to financial mathematics, there is rarely more than one real solution
- typically, the solution corresponds to a rather small number (if $x$ is an interest rate, it is "close" to $0$; if $x$ is a return on investment, it is "close" to $1$ and so $r=1-x$ is close to $0$)
- high accuracy is never required
- analytical solutions are impossible to obtain if the degree of the polynomial is higher than $4$ and, already in the case of degree $3$ the expressions are quite ugly.

So, as LutzL already answered, the more realistic solution is a numerical method and probably Newton would be the simplest (and all calculations can be done with a simple pocket calculator). The only problem is to get easily a reasonable estimate to start the iterations.

To have very good approximations, starting from $0$, we can use either [Newton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method), [Halley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halley's_method) or [Householder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Householder's_method) methods (these are the simplest) which require respectively first, first and second, first, second and third derivatives. I shall not bother you with the formulas (they are in the indicated Wikipedia pages).

Consider your problem which is related to a return on investment. So, settings $x=1+r$ and using the binomial theorem, a cubic polynomial such as $$c_1x+c_2 x^2+c_3 x^3$$ write $$(c_1+c_2+c_3)+(c_1+2 c_2+3 c_3) r+(c_2+3 c_3) r^2+c_3 r^3$$ Now, consider solving for the root of $$F(r)=(c_1+2 c_2+3 c_3) r+(c_2+3 c_3) r^2+c_3 r^3+(c_1+c_2+c_3-a)=0$$ What we need is the value of the function and its derivatives at $r=0$. So, we have $$F(0)=c_1+c_2+c_3-a$$ $$F'(0)=c_1+2 c_2+3 c_3$$ $$F''(0)=2(c_2+3 c_3)$$ $$F'''(0)=6c_3$$ Applied to the equation you gave, this means $$F(0)=\frac{47}{5} \quad F'(0)=315  \quad F''(0)=490 \quad F'''(0)=450$$ Applying the different methods, we then get $$r_{(2)}=-\frac{47}{1575}\approx -0.0298413$$ $$r_{(3)}=-\frac{13912}{455625}\approx -0.0305339$$ $$r_{(4)}=-\frac{67697698273}{2215260140625}\approx-0.0305597$$ while the exact solution would be $-0.0305609$; this means that, using basic arithmetic operations and no algebra, we have been abale to get the result  for five correct figures.

Nevertheless, I suggest you use the first estimate (it was already given by LutzL) and start Newton procedure. The successive iterates would then be $$r_0=-0.0298413$$ $$r_1=-0.0305605$$ $$r_2=-0.0305609$$

The same kind of approach could be used with the same efficiency for any degree of the expression.

**Edit**

In the case of a problem with interest, suppose the equation to be
$$50x + 20 x^2+75x^3 = 6$$ the same method would have given $$x_{(1)}=\frac{3}{25}=0.12$$ $$x_{(2)}=\frac{357}{3125}=0.11424$$ $$x_{(3)}=\frac{87657}{781250}=0.11220096$$ while the solution would be $\approx 0.112763$. And this is not a small interest.

Comment: Wow thanks for the exhaustive answer :)

Comment: You are very welcome !

Answer (score 1):

Your function is monotonically increasing and convex (as long as the $c_k$ stay non-negative). Thus you can use any of Newton's method, regula-falsi with Illinois anti-stalling, secant method, etc. with guaranteed and fast convergence.

Additionally, since the interest rate, outside of usury, is a number $r$ close to $0$ you get for $x=1+r$ the equation
$$
0=75r^3 + 245r^2 + 315r + 9.4
$$
which gives a first (and good) approximation $r=-\frac{9.4}{315}=-0.02984…$ with $x=1+r=0.9701587…$

Comment: and we have also an analytically solution $$\left\{\left\{x\to \frac{1}{45} \left(-4-\frac{434}{\sqrt[3]{85013+9
   \sqrt{90234033}}}+\sqrt[3]{85013+9 \sqrt{90234033}}\right)\right\}$$

Comment: This result is not really interesting in this context, the degree 3 an artifact of the shortness of the example, not characteristic for the general situation.

Comment: aha, i'm wondering, we can solve this equation by roots, this is a fact

Comment: Yes, it is a fact, only not a very useful one, since for degrees larger than 4 such formulas do not exist and financial computations usually concern more than 4 deposits.

Comment: this is a very interesting case that such formulas in the general case not exist (in the general case!!!)

Comment: Is there a way to get this method even more approximate - say 4 decimal accuracy? Does this wok in general? Thanks !

Comment: In fact this computation is the first iteration in the Newton method (executed a la Newton) for $x_0=1$. After the next Newton iteration, the first decimals should be stable, check with a third iteration. -- And yes, that works in general if the first guess is close enough to the solution, like here with $x=1$.